# C++ acceso a atributos: this o className::

Tags: c++

Programando en C++, cuando nos referimos a un atributo de una clase, cuál es la diferencia entre usar 'this' o 'className::'?

```
void Truck::setNumWheels(int numWheels) {
this->numWheels = numWheels;}
```

o

```
void Truck::setNumWheels(int numWheels) {
Truck::numWheels = numWheels;}
```

Gracias

Comment: Hi there, this is [es.so], please translate your question to Spanish, otherwise it will be closed. Bienvenido a [es.so], por favor traduce tu pregunta al Castellano, de lo contrario terminará cerrada. Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay atributos, o campos, que pertenecen a la clase en sí misma, y son compartidos por todas las instancias (objetos) de la clase, mientras que por otro lado hay atributos que pertenecen a las instancias, es decir, son únicos para cada objeto.

Cuando escribes `this` te estás refiriendo a la instancia que ha llamado a un método de la clase, mientras que si pones `Clase::` estás intentando acceder a un campo (atributo o método) de clase.

Piensa en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
class Vehiculo {
    public:
        int identificador;
        static int vehiculosGenerados;
        Vehiculo(int id) {
            this->identificador = id;
            Vehiculo::vehiculosGenerados++;
        }
};

int Vehiculo::vehiculosGenerados = 0;
```

En la clase `Vehiculo`, tenemos dos atributos: `identificador` es un atributo de instancia, es decir, cada vehículo tendrá un identificador; mientras que `vehiculosGenerados` es un atributo de clase (o estático), que pertenece a la clase, y todas las instancias podrán compartir este campo.

Analicemos ahora este código:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    Vehiculo v = new Vehiculo(123);
    cout << v.identificador << endl;    // Se imprimirá 123

    Vehiculo v2 = new Vehiculo(234);
    cout << v2.identificador << endl;    // Se imprimirá 234

    cout << Vehiculo::vehiculosGenerados << endl;    // Se imprimirá 2
}
```

Cada objeto vehículo tiene su identificador, pero la clase `Vehiculo` es la que tiene el atributo `vehiculosGenerados`. Lo puedes conceptualizar como:

```
clase Vehiculo
+----------------------+
|vehiculosGenerados = 2|
+----------------------+

objeto v
+-------------------+
|identificador = 123|
+-------------------+

objeto v2
+-------------------+
|identificador = 234|
+-------------------+
```

**Edición**

En la práctica, C++ no diferencia completamente entre los campos que son atributo de instancia y de clase, ya que permite, por ejemplo, acceder a un atributo de clase mediante cualquier instancia del objeto.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    Vehiculo v = new Vehiculo(123);
    cout << v.identificador << endl;    // Se imprimirá 123

    Vehiculo v2 = new Vehiculo(234);
    cout << v2.identificador << endl;    // Se imprimirá 234

    cout << Vehiculo::vehiculosGenerados << endl;    // Se imprimirá 2
    cout << v.vehiculosGenerados << endl;    // También imprime 2
}
```

Lo que en concepto estaba totalmente separado, en realidad no lo está. Esto es porque los objetos comparten el atributo de clase, haciendo referencia a la misma variable o posición de memoria. Es más, cuando declaras un atributo estático en la clase, te salta un fallo de referencia no definida al intentar leer ese atributo, y tienes que de hecho definir el atributo fuera de la clase para que compile, con lo que conceptualmente lo puedes ver así.

```
clase Vehiculo
+------------------+            Referencia            +----------------------+
|vehiculosGenerados| -------------------------------> |vehiculosGenerados = 2|
+------------------+  (Vehiculo::vehiculosGenerados)  +----------------------+

objeto v                                                   ^           ^
+-------------------+                                      |           |
|identificador = 123|                                      |           |
+-------------------+              Referencia              |           |
|vehiculosGenerados | -------------------------------------+           |
+-------------------+        (v.vehiculosGenerados)                    |
                                                                       |
objeto v2                                                              |
+-------------------+                                                  |
|identificador = 234|                                                  |
+-------------------+                    Referencia                    |
|vehiculosGenerados | -------------------------------------------------+
+-------------------+              (v2.vehiculosGenerados)
```

Pero tienes que tener en cuenta que el puntero `this` solo tiene sentido en el contexto de un método de una clase. Fuera del contexto de una llamada a método, no tiene sentido, ya que precisamente apunta al objeto que invocó al método.

Por tanto, desde fuera de la clase puedes acceder a atributos de instancia solo a través de un objeto y con los operadores punto (**.**) o flecha (**->**); mientras que para un atributo estático puedes hacerlo a través de un objeto o de la clase, con los operadores mencionados y con el operador cuatro puntos (**::**), respectivamente, sin diferencia alguna.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    Vehiculo v(123);                     // Reside en la pila
    Vehiculo * v = new Vehiculo(234);    // En memoria montón

    cout << v.identificador << endl;     // Atributo de instancia con punto
    cout << v2->identificador << endl;   // Atributo de instancia con flecha

    cout << Vehiculo::vehiculosGenerados << endl;    // Atributo de clase con 4 puntos
    cout << v.vehiculosGenerados << endl;    // Atributo de clase a través de objeto
    cout << v2->vehiculosGenerados << endl;  // Atributo de clase a través de objeto
}
```

Ahora bien, los editores pueden generar acceso a campos que son atributos de instancia mediante operador cuatro puntos solo dentro de los métodos de la propia clase.

Esto es porque el operador cuatro puntos es el operador de resolución de ámbito, que permite solucionar un conflicto de nombres cuando un atributo tiene el mismo nombre que una variable o parámetro de un método.

Es más, escribir los 4 puntos es equivalente a escribir el nombre del atributo sin nada, teniendo en cuanta que poner un identificador/nombre de variable sin calificativos siempre hace referencia a la más local.

Imagina que en un método tienes lo siguiente:

```
void Vehiculo::metodo(int identificador) {
    identificador = identificador;              // ¿Atributo o parámetro?
    Vehiculo::identificador = identificador;    // Resolución de ámbito
    this->identificador = identificador;        // Acceso mediante puntero this
}
```

Como se puede ver en la primera instrucción, al escribir `identificador` podemos preguntarnos a qué variable nos referimos, si al atributo o al parámetro, ya que ambas tienen el mismo nombre.

La respuesta es que nos estamos refiriendo siempre a la variable más local, que en este caso **NO es el atributo** con nombre `identificador`, sino el parámetro del método.

De esta forma, la primera instrucción asigna al parámetro el valor que ya tenía, por lo que no hace nada efectivo o significativo.

Por otro lado, al escribir `Vehiculo::identificador` estás indicando que se accede al campo `identificador` de la clase `Vehiculo`, y como es un atributo de instancia, se accede al atributo del objeto que ha realizado la llamada (y que es apuntado por `this`).

Una forma alternativa de resolver el conflicto de nombres entre el atributo y el parámetro, es utilizar el puntero `this`, para acceder al campo de ese objeto, y diferenciarlo del parámetro del método.

Comment: Perfecta explicación, gracias. Pero me queda una duda. Los IDEs (como Visual Studio o CLion) que generan automáticamente getters y setters, construyen estos métodos con nombreClase::. Si lo que quieres obtener/modificar es el atributo de esa instancia, esta construcción debería de ser con el 'this', verdad? Es que no quería alargarme con mi pregunta inicial, pero de aquí viene mi duda.

Comment: He añadido una edición que completaré cuando tenga un poco más de tiempo entre hoy y mañana.

Comment: Ya completé la edición. Espero que te ayude. Saludos!

Comment: Muy bien explicado. Gracias por la ayuda.